# Declaring a Queue/HashSet

Tags: java, hashmap, queue

I'm learning about HashSets and Queues and I have difficulty understanding why a Queue/hashMap/other java.util predefined data structures is declared as :

```
Set<T> h =  new HashSet<T>();
Queue<T> q = new LinkedList<T>();
```

I understand that `<T>` can be an Integer/String/other data type and this is to ensure that we add the same data type to the data structure. However, I don't understand why I have to declare it as a new HashMap, when it is a HashSet. I am following [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/queue.html). Is there any way to know that a HashSet/Queue/others have to be declared as only a HashMap/LinkedList? Thanks a lot! Please tell me if I have to explain/modify my question.

Comment: This: `HashSet<T> h =  new HashMap<T>();` doesn't make sense and shouldn't compile. You cannot assign a Map to a Set, and you can't declare or define a Map with just one generic parameter.

Comment: Sorry, it's Set= HashSet. Ill edit it

Comment: Yes, I got why I cant assign a map to a set with just one parameter. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called coding to interface than implementation. Having a reference of interface gives u flexibility to change the implementation later if required. For example today, you are using
HashSet so you define it as:

```
Set<T> h =  new HashSet<T>();
```

but if later you realized that you need a `LinkedHashSet` so simply replace it

```
Set<T> h =  new LinkedHashSet<T>();
```

without changing any other code. And that is why this is referred as a good coding practice.

Comment: So, it all depends on how/what application the hash set is defined for?

Comment: It is a good coding practice, which allows you to give flexibilty.

Comment: Ok, one more question. What does Queue q = new Queue(); mean then?

Comment: Because it's letting me compile it but I can't use the queue functions.

Comment: You are able to assign a LinkedList to Queue because LinkedList implements a DeQueue interface which is extended from Queue interface. you should be able to call all the methods available in queue interface.

Comment: Thanks, got it. One last question. How will I know which two types are compatible? As in if a queue= linkedlist but not a queue=hashmap? Sorry if it's a dumb question.

Comment: @PR Learning about Collections hierarchies, Map, Set and Queue will help you about the compatibility. Also compiler will always flag when you try to do something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply following the rule of "coding to the interface rather than the implementation". This will give your program greater flexibility and allow for easier testing. It's much easier to isolate and mock classes when using interfaces; it's much easier to use factories for object creation and to use tools such as Guice or Spring to do dependency injection if you use interfaces.

Comment: Got it, but how can I avoid always declaring the  <T> to integer or string? Is there a way to declare it as a variable which could be changed?